# Google Maps API - Find matching place between two points?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I explain my issue in below image (I'm sorry I speak English not well).

I'm using Google Maps Directions API to calculate directions between start point and destination and there is a place between them (you see in the map). How can I know that place is on route?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of (and I have used this method) is thus:

When you make a directions request, you receive a DirectionsResult object.
If you drill down into that result you can get latitudes and longitudes.
If you are using the JavaScript API, for example:

```
// Every step is about 22 LatLngs per mile; we'll try one LatLng per 3
// miles or so:
    var specRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < specRoute.path.length; j = j + 171) {
        var lattotal = latarr.push(specRoute.path[j].lat());
        var lngtotal = lngarr.push(specRoute.path[j].lng());
    }
```

In this example I am formatting arrays of lats and lngs to be compared to a lot of other lats and lngs in a php file elsewhere.  It sounds like you only need to check one latlng so it should be simpler.

What I did thereafter (and what you could do) is to determine how close to the path your point is required to be, and write some logic to check.  You could do that with straight latitude and longitude numbers, or convert to another distance measurement (miles, meters, etc).

There is a negative aspect in that you will have to deal with converging longitude lines the farther north you go (in the Northern hemisphere).
I used a regression fit workaround but there is probably a better way.

There may also be a better method for doing this, but this is the only way I could think of on past projects.